# Indexing 6 sprocket rear derailleur, having trouble reaching largest sprocket

Tags: gears, derailleur-rear

I'm trying to index my rear gears after replacing my 6 sprocket freewheel. I've set the limit screws fine, but I didn't have enough play in the barrel adjusters to make much adjustment, so I undid the clamp to release the cable, tightened both adjusters up then let them out a couple of turns, then reattached the cable finger tight.

I'm finding, though, that I can get the smallest cogs to change okay, but by the time I reach the lowest gear, it won't move to the largest cog, just this awful clacking of gears, even though by eye the jockey wheel is in line with it and the b tension gives plenty of room, about 1cm.

I thought I was meant to tighten the cable with the adjuster to amend this, but nothing makes a difference, I feel like I need to loosen or tighten the cable overall with the clamp bolt, but I don't know which way to go, am I doing something drastically wrong here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This can be caused by some reasons. Please add pictures of the freewheel, the a picture of derailleur from the bottom.

Comment: I couldn't really get a very clear shot from underneath, are these any use?

Comment: Did you replace the freewheel with one with identical sized lowest and biggest gears? You might have put a freewheel on that has a greater gear range than your derailleur can handle

Comment: Not that I'm aware, it was reaching the largest cog before I undid the cable, albeit not perfectly, hence why, in my inexperience, I thought I might need to start completely from scratch.

Comment: Just checked. Can't tell exactly unless I take the whole thing off again, but I wound a bit of old wire around the large cog on both, and there was only a couple of mm difference which is probably just my imprecise winding, certainly nothing drastic between them.

Comment: It looks like your derailleur is bent little bit (or unscrewed). You also have to be sure that your cable is in good shape, and going in the right place in the holding screw under the derailleur.

Comment: Yes, at the time I had the cable removed and have replaced it with a fresh one, I found that the high limit was not far enough inboard, and having tweaked that I can reach the large sprocket again. I can't seem to get the shifting to go smoothly in both directions - if I index it so it changes onto and off the large cogs smoothly, it stops coming up from the small cog easily, and vice versa, is that just a matter of finding a very precise sweet spot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returned to this this morning, and have found that the high limit screw could be let out a bit more, and now that is done the chain reaches the large sprocket just fine! Apologies for being dense!

I am now finding that I can index it fine for going up from the low sprocket, or coming down from the large sprocket, but not both, but I'll work on that....

Comment: This answers the question - would you be able to click the tick/checkbox on the left to mark it as the accepted answer?